# What is a non-integer string?

Tags: meaning, terminology

My English is not so good. Can someone please tell me what a **non-integer string** is?

Comment: It might be a string which is not a text representation of an integer value. Please provide more context.

Comment: This is a technical term, and the average English-speaker would not know either. Because this is StackExchange, where there are many people familiar with software programming, you will find an answer, but usually it is best to ask specialists about specialist terminology, as opposed to this site, where the expertise is about standard, general use of English.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to show us some of the context where you found "non-integer string"? That will make it easier for someone to write an appropriate answer. Without more context, we can only guess.

Comment: @choster If someone asks us a question about specialized terminology, we can usually still answer it has _as a question about learning English,_ not as a question about the subject matter of the specialized field. For example, in this case we might be able to explain the ambiguity of "non-integer string" and how the context resolves it—or not, depending on what the OP is trying to get at. [Here's](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2468/6700) a related meta question.

Answer (score 1):

What is probably meant by

> non-integer string

is the ascii representation of some input which would not evaluate to a number, the is not consisting of only numeric digits

> [0...9]
>   17
>   123456789
>   0xabc

are all examples of integers.

any other characters

> [a...z, A...Z] and other non-digit characters would be fine.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion for non-technical readers, integers are numerical digits.  Characters 0-9 represent numbers in number bases up to 10.  In computer work, it is common to use base 16 numbers (hexadecimal).  Letters a-f are used to represent hexadecimal digits greater than 9.  The 0x at the beginning is a formatting convention that indicates that the characters (numbers and letters) are a hexadecimal representation of a number.

Comment: @fixer1234 "Integer" ≠ "numerical digit". The whole answer, though, and all the other current answers, are probably off-topic, since they're about a specialized topic and not about learning English.

Comment: @BenKovitz, yeah, probably could have worded the comment more accurately.  I looked at some of the Meta discussion and couldn't find clear direction on where the line is on specialized topics (or how "English" is defined for site scope).

Comment: @fixer1234 [Here's](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2468/6700) one. ;)

Comment: @BenKovitz, I had read that one.  Not really useful guidance in this case.  In fact what I took away was that this question was probably on-topic.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

More context would be fine, but my programming background hints me that a non-integer string is one that is not a text representation of an integer value. 
Some examples of integer strings:

> 45
>   -5
>   +100500
>   0xffab

etc, that is, any format format for integers as accepted by, say, scanf or atoi functions.

**A non-integer string is everything else.**

Comment: In C, for instance, `atoi()` *accepts* certain non-integer-only strings, which is one of the reasons it and its friends, along with `scanf()` (for other reasons) are best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This is a computer-related term.  **String** refers to a sequence of characters that is used as data.  The characters can include letters, numbers, and symbols.

An **integer** is a "whole" number, i.e., a number with no decimal or fractional portion.  If you are referring to a single digit, that is an integer.

Numerical values can be used for mathematical calculations.  Non-numerical values can't, they are treated as text.  But numbers can also be treated like text.

"String" typically refers to data that is treated as text.  "Non-integer string" includes both a number reference and a text reference, implying that your source is using a more general definition of "string", to include any sequence of characters (text or numerical), so I'll assume that here.

To complicate things, data can be stored as a predefined type, which ensures that it will be used in the intended way.  Text is one type.  Numeric data can be stored as an integer value or a "floating point" value, which is a number that can have a fractional part.

A string isn't limited to a stored value, it can be created on-the-fly.  That can include expressions or formulas that are evaluated by the software to produce a string.  Also, a string of numerical data that is stored as text, or results from manipulating text, can be converted by the software into a number that can then be used in calculations.

So **non-integer string** could refer to a number of things depending on how precisely the term is being used, or the context, including but probably not limited to:

- a sequence of characters that does not evaluate to a numerical value that can be used in a math calculation
- a sequence of characters that does not evaluate to an integer
- characters stored as a  datatype of text
- numerical values stored as a floating point number

Answer (score -1):

Probably a string that disallows entering of integer values. Some kind of special variable or maybe a domain that may be custom. Maybe has a regular expression mask that prohibits input of integer values.